# Tosfos and the rain proof sukkah

Tags: sukkah, tosfot, masechet-sukkah

The bottom Tosfos on Sukkah 2a (DH Ki Avid) talks about how it must be that the scach of a sukkah can't be rain proof, because if it was, then when the Rabbanan say that rain on sukkos is a bad sign (Taanis 2a) wouldn't be true because we could just put up rain proof scach. But I don’t understand Tosfos, for I can put up a tent inside my Sukkah (as long as there isn't a there isn't a one tefach wide flat area - Sukkah 10a), and I can eat and sleep inside the tent and also abrogate the reason it’s a "bad sign.”

Comment: I went ahead and added sources and fixed up your tags as well as edited to make it a bit more readable. If you disagree you can rollback or edit further. I might add that the Tosfos in question is specifically discussing the criterion of Sukkas Diras Keva, so perhaps that makes a difference here. Take a look at the line in Tosfos where he explains that the Sukkah, called as such because of the Schach, must have temporary Schach - this point is explained further in the Maharam.

Answer (score 1):

> it must be that the scach of a sukkah can't be rain proof because if it was then when the rabbanim say that rain on sukkos is a bad sign wouldn't be true because we could just put up rain proof scach. But I dont understand tosfos, for I can put up a tent inside my sukkah (as long as there isn't a there isn't a one tefach wide flat area.

Note that Tosfas is talking about the Schach, i.e. the Succah itself - the tent is **not** the Succah. Presumably, Tosfos understands that if the Succah **itself** is what is judged in the criteria of being exempted, and holds one which will never come to exemption is not a kosher Succah.

Another, slightly different possibility is that Tosfas holds that everything is taken into account for the exemption, but holds that it's still a bad sign if you're only there because of a reason external to the Succah, whilst if the reason you're okay is because of the Succah itself it cannot be seen as a 'rejection' of the Succah. To riff of the example of Chazal, the first case is like wearing a waterproof face covering, the second is like the master not throwing the cup of water you just fetched in your face at all.